# Can I minimize arc length in dot graph?

Tags: graphviz, dot, bayesian-networks

I have a rather constrained dot graph that is not coming out how I want.

The graphs are intended to represent a dynamic Bayesian network and has an arbitrary number of time slices. I need all nodes in one time slice to be ordered vertically in the same subgraph and each subgraph to be aligned horizontally and preferably equidistant.

Below is the messy DBN generated by the code at the bottom of this question - it's a relatively simple example but should illustrate the problem. I'd prefer to have the arcs from the 't-1' to 't' subgraph and the 't' to 't+1' subgraph look identical, and avoid looping arcs like 'c(t-1)' to 'e(t)' and also have the subgraphs equidistant.

Adjusting the weight of 'c(t-1)' to 'e(t)' does nothing and the code to generate this dot file should be general.

I'm not attached to dot if there's a better program for this type of problem.

[image]

The code to generate the graph is:

```
digraph G {

    1 [ label = "a(t-1)" ];
    2 [ label = "b(t-1)" ];
    3 [ label = "c(t-1)" ];
    4 [ label = "d(t-1)" ];
    5 [ label = "e(t-1)" ];
    6 [ label = "a(t)" ];
    7 [ label = "b(t)" ];
    8 [ label = "c(t)" ];
    9 [ label = "d(t)" ];
    10 [ label = "e(t)" ];
    11 [ label = "a(t+1)" ];
    12 [ label = "b(t+1)" ];
    13 [ label = "c(t+1)" ];
    14 [ label = "d(t+1)" ];
    15 [ label = "e(t+1)" ];
    rankdir=TB

    edge[style=invis];

    {
        rank=same;
        K_1 [style=invis] ;
        K_2 [style=invis] ;
        K_3 [style=invis] ;
        K_1 -> K_2 ;
        K_2 -> K_3 ;
    }


    subgraph cluster1 {
    style=dotted ;
        1 -> 2;
        2 -> 3;
        3 -> 4;
        4 -> 5;
        label="t-1" ;
    }

    subgraph cluster2 {
    style=dotted ;
        6 -> 7;
        7 -> 8;
        8 -> 9;
        9 -> 10;
        label="t" ;
    }

    subgraph cluster3 {
    style=dotted ;
        11 -> 12;
        12 -> 13;
        13 -> 14;
        14 -> 15;
        label="t+1" ;
    }

    K_3 -> 11[style=invis] ;
    K_2 -> 6[style=invis] ;
    K_1 -> 1[style=invis] ;

    edge[constraint=false,style=solid] ;
    3 -> 10 ;

    8 -> 15 ;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

Changed the rank direction to LR and used order of appearance for ordering in the subgraph.

[image]

```
digraph G {

    rankdir=LR

    edge[style=invis];

    subgraph cluster1 {
        style=dotted ;
        rank=same ;
        K_1 [ style=invis ] ;
        1 [ label = "a(t-1)" ];
        2 [ label = "b(t-1)" ];
        3 [ label = "c(t-1)" ];
        4 [ label = "d(t-1)" ];
        5 [ label = "e(t-1)" ];
        label="t-1" ;
    }

    subgraph cluster2 {
        style=dotted ;
        rank=same ;
        K_2 [style=invis] ;
        6 [ label = "a(t)" ];
        7 [ label = "b(t)" ];
        8 [ label = "c(t)" ];
        9 [ label = "d(t)" ];
        10 [ label = "e(t)" ];
        label="t" ;
    }

    subgraph cluster3 {
        style=dotted ;
        rank=same ;
        K_3 [style=invis] ;
        11 [ label = "a(t+1)" ];
        12 [ label = "b(t+1)" ];
        13 [ label = "c(t+1)" ];
        14 [ label = "d(t+1)" ];
        15 [ label = "e(t+1)" ];
        label="t+1" ;
    }

    K_1 -> K_2 -> K_3 ;

    edge[constraint=false,style=solid] ;
    3 -> 10 ;

    8 -> 15 ;

}
```